# How to make a GET Request for a unique register with AXIOS and NodeJS/Express

Tags: node.js, api, express, axios, endpoint

I'm trying to make GET request to external API (Rick and Morty API). The objective is setting a GET request for unique character, for example "Character with id=3". At the moment my endpoint is:

Routes file:

```
import CharacterController from '../controllers/character_controller'
const routes = app.Router()
routes.get('/:id', new CharacterController().get)
export default routes
```

Controller file:

```
  async get (req, res) {
    try {
      const { id } = req.params
      const oneChar = await axios.get(`https://rickandmortyapi.com/api/character/${id}`)

      const filteredOneChar = oneChar.data.results.map((item) => {
        return {
          name: item.name,
          status: item.status,
          species: item.species,
          origin: item.origin.name
        }
      })
      console.log(filteredOneChar)

      return super.Success(res, { message: 'Successfully GET Char request response', data: filteredOneChar })
    } catch (err) {
      console.log(err)
    }
  }
```

The purpose of map function is to retrieve only specific Character data fields.
But the code above doesn't work. Please let me know any suggestions, thanks!

Comment: what is the response you are recieving?

Comment: `oneChar.data` is a single object. `const filteredOneChar = { name: oneChar.data.name, ...`

Answer (score 0):

First of all I don't know why your controller is a `class`. Revert that and export your function like so:

```
const axios = require('axios');
// getCharacter is more descriptive than "get" I would suggest naming 
// your functions with more descriptive text
exports.getCharacter = async (req, res) => {
```

Then in your routes file you can easily import it and attach it to your route handler:

```
const { getCharacter } = require('../controllers/character_controller');

index.get('/:id', getCharacter);
```

Your routes imports also seem off, why are you creating a new `Router` from `app`? You should be calling:

```
const express = require('express');
const routes = express.Router();
```

next go back to your controller. Your logic was all off, if you checked the api you would notice that the `character/:id` endpoint responds with 1 character so `.results` doesnt exist. The following will give you what you're looking for.

```
exports.getCharacter = async (req, res) => {
  try {
    const { id } = req.params;
    const oneChar = await axios.get(
      `https://rickandmortyapi.com/api/character/${id}`
    );
    console.log(oneChar.data);
    // return name, status, species, and origin keys from oneChar
    const { name, status, species, origin } = oneChar.data;
    const filteredData = Object.assign({}, { name, status, species, origin });

    res.send(filteredData);
  } catch (err) {
    return res.status(400).json({ message: err.message });
  }
};
```